# MFC EditBrowse control does not display the folder icon at runtime

Tags: visual-studio, mfc

I have a dialog type application that includes a MFC EditBrowse Control.  This control includes a folder/magnifier icon on the right side where the user is supposed to click to bring up a folder browser pop-up.

[image: screen grab of what it should look like]

That folder/magnifier icon displays properly in the dialog editor within Visual Studio, but at runtime it displays as a plain flat button. It behaves properly otherwise - that is, the browser pop-up pops up and the selected folder is displayed when the user clicks OK.

When run with the debugger a message is displayed in the VS Output Window saying "Can't load bitmap: 4299".  That message is displayed after the CDialogEx::OnInitDialog() line within my OnInitDialog().

I've written test programs and they display the icon properly. I've also added additional EditBrowse controls in my original program, but they experience the same problem and just add another line of "can't load bitmap".  I've also added other MFC controls and some of them also do not display their icons (or other stuff).

I've managed to affect the problem slightly by making calls to EnableBrowseButton() and EnableFolderBrowswButton() from my OnInitDialog.  If I do that, I get an icon that looks like 3 horizontal dots:

[image]

which is better, but I'd prefer the folder/magnifier icon.

It's a complicated enough application I'd rather not re-write it from the beginning and furthermore I'd like to understand what is going on.  I'm fairly certain this is a result of adding/deleting controls as the app was developed, but don't have a good idea on where to begin tracking down where things went awry.

Thoughts on how to debug this? BTW, this is VS 2010.

Comment: Check your *.rc file. Do you see this line: `#if !defined(_AFXDLL) ... #include "afxribbon.rc" ... #endif`? That's where that resource should be (`"browe32.bmp"`)

Comment: Thank you for the response @BarmakShemirani! I do NOT see the #include "afxribbon.rc" line. But then I don't see that in a test program that works properly, either. I did a search on "afxribbon" in the working sample directory and came up with hits in the .sdf, pdb, tlog, pch and stdafx.obj files. But I seem to get the same basic results in the non-working sample. Likewise a search on browse32 (I'm assuming a typo in your 'browe32.bmp'?) shows results in the .sdf and pch for both working and non-working programs. I also should have indicated this is VS 2010 I'm working in.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Yikes!!  You've led me to a fix/workaround!  I finally just stuck in a #include "afxribbon.rc" in the app.rc file ( no #if !def stuff) and now I have my folder icon.  If you want to write that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CMFCEditBrowseCtrl` uses the Visual Manager to load the bitmap from MFC resources.

This resource is loaded in `"afxribbon.rc"`

Make sure the following these lines are included in the main *.rc file (this is how VS Wizard creates the *.rc file)

```
#if !defined(_AFXDLL)
#include "afxribbon.rc"   // MFC ribbon and control bar resources
#endif
```

(I guess you can omit the `#if/end` statement, but it's probably there for a reason)

Alternatively, [`CMFCEditBrowseCtrl::SetBrowseButtonImage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfceditbrowsectrl-class?view=vs-2019#setbrowsebuttonimage) can be used to assign user icon.

Comment: I have done further experimentation on this and found that the 'cause' of the problem is from selecting "Use MFC in a Static Library" versus "Use MFC in a Shared DLL" in the project Configuration Properties -> General -> Use of MFC. Toggling between those two settings will break/fix the icon display. 
The #if !defined... in @BarmakShemirani 's solution is necessary if you toggle between those two settings.  If you're staying with Static, you don't need the #if/end bit.
I wish someone could point me to the MS explanation for this.

Comment: I spoke/wrote too soon.  Adding the #inc ribbon bit does fix the problem, but then causes issues with the IDE opening the .rc file when trying to open (for example) the dialogs. (error RC2188 ...RibbonStyle2007Aqua.rc2(6)
So, not so complete a fix/workaround :(  
The lesson seems to be, don't fiddle with that Shared/Static MFC setting.

Comment: Bah!  Found the issue, but not soon enough to edit my previous comment!

The #if-#inc-#end stuff  _must_ go down at the bottom of the <proj>.rc file, inside the #ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED section.
Otherwise, it will cause issues when trying to edit the resources from within the IDE.